# Unicode in Python 3 shows just question marks

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I am trying to use the mercury symbol with unicode U+263F in my python shell via anaconda. But if I give the
command `'\u263F'` in the shell, the output is just a question mark. The unicode symbol of U+00E9 for example  works. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Maybe the font you are using doesn't have this symbol.

Comment: Works for me (on Linux): ☿. Very likely you're lacking proper fonts, or your console is not enabled for Unicode. Hard to tell without knowing the details of your system.

Comment: Try _'DejaVu Sans Mono'_ font.

Comment: My first guess is that the terminal you are running in doesn't support Unicode. Are you by chance working on MS Windows? If so maybe you can find a Unicode-enabled terminal for Windows. If Linux or macOS, hmm, dunno, I would expect most or all terminals to be Unicode-enabled by default.

Comment: if you're on Linux, try running the `locale` command. The `LANG=?` variable should have "`UTF-8`" in it (for example mine is `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`). If you see `LANG=C` you're using an ASCII-only locale.

Comment: I suppose that is the error. Do I have to load a new font into anaconda or does this have something to do with my Computer?